# How to refactor ngFor when element uses the iteration variable on the element?

Tags: angular, for-loop, ngfor, angular17

I have this

```
<div
    *ngFor="let dt of totals"
    [ngClass]="{ up: dt.isUp }"
>
    <span> {{ dt }}</span>
</div>
```

and I want to refactor to angular v17 syntax

```
@for (dt of totals; track $index) {
    <span>{{ dt }}</span>
}
```

How do I refactor the `[ngClass]` on the `<div>`?

I tried this but obviously It doesn't work because the variable `dt` is not yet defined inthe `<div>`

```
<div [ngClass]="{ up: dt.isUp }">
    @for (dt of totals; track $index) {
        <span>{{ dt }}</span>
    }
</div>
```

I could try this but I don't want an extra `ng-container` on every element:

```
<div>
    @for (dt of totals; track $index) {
        <ng-container [ngClass]="{ up: dt.isUp }">
            <span>{{ dt }}</span>
        </ng-container>
    }
 </div>
```

What's the official way to do this?

edit:
Thanks for the help, I got the resolution I needed. The question is silly because I forgot that the *ngFor repeats the element it is in and its children. I forgot that and thought it was only repeating its children. That is basic pre-v17 angular. I'll leave this question in case this catches anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are creating multiple divs, by using the `*ngFor` so the equivalent of the same will be the below code.

The line where you place the `*ngFor` get repeated.

```
@for (dt of totals; track $index) {
    <div [ngClass]="{ up: dt.isUp }" >
        <span> {{ dt }}</span>
    </div>
}
```

If you do not want the `div` tag, then you can add the `[ngClass]` to the `span`, the `ngClass` must be attached to an HTML element. Since the class is present in html, we cannot use `ng-container` because there is no tag present in the HTML during rendering!

```
@for (dt of totals; track $index) {
    <span [ngClass]="{ up: dt.isUp }"> {{ dt }}</span>
}
```